# how to tell webpack that do not minify and pack js files

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm using vue-cli webpack boilerplate in this address:

[vuejs-templates/webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

I want webpack not to minify and pack js files in dev mode.
how it can be achieved?
the problem is that we have a huge tested asp.net webforms app, and it already includes jquery and bootstrap, in a way that can not bypassed.
and i have conflicting jquery and bootstrap.js with vue. that i can not debug them in dev mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you referring to the `vue-cli webpack boilerplate`: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

If so the production build (npm run build) is minified and mangled by uglify. To change its behaviour go to `build/webpack.prod.conf.js` and edit the uglify production options. You can probably delete it all together based on what you require, i.e. no compression, no mangle, or set these options as below:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: false,
  mangle: false,
})
```

check out the webpack docs for more info: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin

If you are having issues also with it packing vendor files this config is in the same file. Look for:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  ...
})
```

However if you don't need it to include JQuery or Bootstrap.js in the app then can you not just avoid importing them into it? Then simply link to those 2 libaries seperately within your html.

**EDIT**

To address any issues you have with ESLint wanting a `$` value, or any other global that you are including outside of your app, simply edit your `.eslint.js` config file adding some global params or in the case of JQuery you can add the JQuery env variable:

```
env: {
    'jquery': true
}

# or to set global vars that would be available on your apps window, i.e. window.foo
globals: {
  'foo': true
},
```

check out eslint for further info: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: Last thing first! yes, i don't need to include those jquery and bootstrap libraries. Problem is that i cannot use $ inside .vue files with webpack, eslint fucks everywhere that something is undefined, no unused var & so on. is there any simple solution for this one?

Comment: checking the other part of answer, but i need it in `npm run dev`, so, i think i should edit `build/webpack.dev.conf.js`, I Test and report back.

Comment: I've updated the answer to help with your eslint issue. In regards to your `webpack.dev.conf.js` this by default won't be compressing but it does add source maps. However if you fix the eslint issue you may be able to leave this as is because those source maps are useful to speed up debugging.

Comment: did you get it sorted?

Comment: yes, you pointed me to the right direction. essentially, what i was looking was to debug `ES2015` codes, and founded that webpack(and vue-loader) are converting *.vue files to normal, old fashioned, browser understandable code(am i right?). i changed my point of view, and the most useful part was your explanation of `global` and `env` part that saved my night, thanks in advance. now i use sourcemaps, and need minify and uglify when build for production. and finally, i am confused, by all the concepts from gulp and bower, to browserify and webpack, to amd, commonjs ,requirejs and so on ...

Comment: thanks in advance, comment was to short, to write this thank part ;-)

Comment: how about a toturial in stack documentation? i check and it lacks in webpack (and other parts, npm, gulp, grunt, and others).

Comment: no worries, in regards to what vue's parser does yes it converts the templates you write into plain js. As for a documentation on SO I'm not sure whats out there but I know what you mean - there's a lot going on with apps nowadays and it takes a lot of learning. Just keep plugging / testing and of course check the resources for webpack as that'll certainly clear up most things. One thing I'd add is that the vue-cli is solid so even if you don't know all its working parts you should be able to get a great app environment up and running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129135/discussion-between-ahmad-molaie-and-guyc).

Comment: its not really clear to me how to get it to not mangle the vendor libraries. I see the section. What am I supposed to do with it?

Comment: @robertotomás if you can see where webpack is pulling in uglify, i.e. `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` then pass the `mangle` option as above. If this isn't working could it be that you are using minified (and mangled) versions of your vendor libraries? Therefore uglify isn't doing anything, the files already look like that ...